App Won't Download
I have a TCL_T501C, Cricket Wireless, US Android, (I am in Canada, on "roaming" network,) I have 2 Google accounts, the country in "account 1" is set to United States, while the country of "account 2" is set to Canada, and I am not able to download the RBC (Canadian bank) mobile app or the Walmart Canada app on neither of my 2 accounts, after clearing the cache, (on account 1 it says "Your device isn't compatible with this version", and "This app isn't available", and on account 2 it says "Looking for RBC Mobile? This app won't work for your device"). What do I need to do to be able to download the app?

Assuming that the country setting in the account has not just been changed.

Some apps from a different country can be installed by

Using an account setup for that country.  Really set up for that country, which includes a payment method and address.
And using a VPN


Others can not be installed unless you are in that country, you can not fool it.


In your case, Account-2 says "App wont work for your device".  This is likely the truth.  Account-1 is failing because its in the wrong country.
Check the compatibility list on Google Play

What do you mean by "has not just been changed"? How far back does the country setting in the account need to be changed in order for an app from a different country to download? (I changed it 3 to 6 months ago.) Also, are you saying that in my case there is no option for me to download those apps? If there is a solution, please give step by step process.
